# Magento Table does njot exist Error

Tags: database, magento

I am beginner in `magento` framework. I am developing Custom extension which shows product grid in custom menu at admin side.

Everything was working correctly and suddenly i got following error which says `catalog_product_entity_dropdown` is not exist.

- I have no idea why this table is used. Please explain.
- Is it default magento table?
- How do i know from which file the error is coming ?

  ```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'offer.catalog_product_entity_dropdown' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attr_table`
  INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '1') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `attr_table`
  INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '1') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `attr_table`
  INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '1') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `attr_table`
  INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '1') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `attr_table`
  INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '1') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_dropdown` AS `attr_table`
  INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '1') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

'catalog_product_entity_dropdown' is not default magento table.
So you need to check whether you are using this table in some custom module or not.

If yes, then you will need to check that module's entry in core_resource table.
If it is found, then you can remove this entry from table (if catalog_product_entity_dropdown is the only table related to this module) or downgrade module's version in core_resource table and remove all references of tables which are related to this module.

Then clear magento cache and reload page.

Now table will be created.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any option to check in which module it is created? There is no scripts executed through my custom module and no entries are there in core_resource table. Is there any way to know the module name from the error?

Comment: Issue solved! By mistake some system attributes were created through code. I have deleted them from `eav_attribute` table and all works fine now. :)